# SQL Partition by but not including the current element in the partition

Tags: sql, partition

I am trying to do the following. I have a table of records for example:

```
----------
Elements: a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,d,d,d,d,e,e,e,e,e,
----------
DataRate: 1,2,2,2,5,6,2,3,4,9,5,5,3,2,4,5,5,3,4,5,6,2,4
```

I want to calculate Average Data rate without including the current element.
For Example: The third column will be   AvgDataRateNotIncludingCurrentElement
So the DataRate in Row where Element a is present will not include the DataRate of element a, while calculating the DataRate

I know I can do partition over, Element and get average, but want to partition over Element without present element being in the calculation.

I hope I was able to explain the problem.

Comment: Do you want to exclude only the current value or all "a"?  Tag the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the current row only:

```
select (sum(datarate) over () - datarate) / (count(*) over () - 1) as average
```

If you want to exclude the current row *and* partition by the element:

```
select (sum(datarate) over (partition by element) - datarate
       ) /
       nullif(count(*) over () - count(*) over (partition by element) , 0) as average
```

If you want to exclude the all of the same element, then:

```
select (sum(datarate) over () -
        sum(datarate) over (partition by element)
       ) /
       (count(*) over () - 
        count(*) over (partition by element)
       ) as average
```